# Is there a safe way to cast void* to class pointer in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I am using a C library and I'm passing a "user pointer" to it. When I want to obtain the user pointer the library returns it as `void*`. I'm currently using `static_cast` in order to de-reference the members of the original pointer.

So my question is: is there a way to check if the `static_cast` succeeded?

As far as I know `static_cast` will not return a `nullptr` on failure, but rather, if I attempt to de-reference the resulting failed pointer it would be UB and probably crash the program...

Comment: Any cast is inherently unsafe.  The onus is upon the programmer to ensure the cast is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `static_cast` is correct here.

Assuming that the `void*` value is only copied inside the C library, `static_cast` will return the original pointer value pointing to the passed object if you cast it to a pointer of the same type as it was originally.

Under some conditions you may also cast to a different type, the rules are those of `reinterpret_cast` (which simply casts via two `static_cast`s with `void*` intermediate).

If you cast it to any type not allowed under those rules, e.g. an unrelated class type, trying to access the object through the pointer will cause undefined behavior. There is no way of detecting this mistake. You need to take care of doing it correctly yourself.

Comment: Yeah I guess there is no way... I'm also programming in C# and there you can use the `as` operator to check if a base class variable actually holds a derived class object, and if not the resulting derived class variable would be null. I was hoping there would be something similar in C++ for void* and class pointer, but I guess no.

Comment: @JohnyP. Such a check between base and derived classes (at least if they are polymorphic) is also possible in C++ with `dynamic_cast`, but `void*` is explicitly meant to drop any type information. If you know that the object that it is pointing to has some shared base class, but you just don't know the derived class, then if you do it properly a combination of `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` can work.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is: is there a way to check if the `static_cast` succeeded?

No. It's either correct or your program will have *undefined behavior*.

> As far as I know `static_cast` will not return a `nullptr` on failure, but rather, if I attempt to de-reference the resulting failed pointer it would be UB

Yes, exactly that. So, when using `static_cast` you must be sure that the `void*` is actually pointing at an object of the type you cast to (or is a legal up or down cast).